# How do i factor out the vector $\vec{a}$?

Tags: vectors

Hello i have come to the following expression and i would like to factor $\vec{a}$ in some way so that i can get the aceleration, but i am in doubt on how to do this, can someone help me ?

$$\vec{a} + \frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}}{c^2-u^2}\vec{v} = \frac{q}{m}\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}(\vec{E}+\vec{u}\times\vec{B})$$

Comment: What do these brackets stand for?

Comment: nothing really, they are there only to separete the terms

Comment: Separate from what? The equality sign has the least precedence level, the brackets just make it more confusing.

Comment: well originally i was trying to factor out the $\vec{a}$ so those brackets would separate the $\vec{a}$ from some other vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

If you define $\vect{a}$ as a column vector, then $\vect{a}\cdot \vect{b}$ is just $\vect{a}^T\vect{b}$ therefore, you can also write your equation as

$$
\left[\vect{1} + \frac{\vect{v} \vect{v}^T }{c^2-u^2} \right]\vect{a}  = \frac{q}{m}\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2}}(\vect{E} + \vect{u}\times\vect{B})
$$

which is just a problem of the form $\vect{A}\vect{x} = \vect{b}$, $\vect{x} = \vect{a}$

Comment: is the 1 a vector ?

Comment: @FelipeDilho ${\bf 1}$ is the identity matrix

Comment: Why is $(\vec{v}\vec{v}^{T})\vec{a}$ equal to $(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{v}) \vec{v}$?

Comment: @stressed-out $({\bf a}\cdot {\bf v}){\bf v} = {\bf v}({\bf v}\cdot{\bf a})$

Comment: @caverac: I agree with the identity you wrote now, but the identity I'm asking about is a different one:  the first expression is something scaled in the direction of $\vec{a}$ while the second expression is something scaled in the direction of $\vec{v}$. Unless $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ were linearly dependent, why should these two agree?

Comment: Because $(\vec{v}\vec{v}^T) \vec{a}=\vec{v} \vec{v}^T\vec{a} = \vec{v} (\vec{v}\cdot \vec{a})$. Since the euclidean metric is symmetric we have $ a \cdot v = v \cdot a$. Because It's a scalar $v (v\cdot a) = (a \cdot v) v$

Comment: @Triatticus: Your first identity which is the identity I'm talking about (and it's this identity that we need to have for that factorization, I guess) is obviously wrong. For a counter-example, take $\vec{v}=\vec{e_1}=(1,0)$ and $\vec{a}=\vec{e_2}=(0,1)$. Then $(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})\vec{a}=\vec{a}$ but $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ and $\vec{a} \neq \vec{0}$.

Comment: $v v^T\neq v \cdot v$ It's actually a matrix/array, I believe it's called a dayad formed from the outer product of two vectors.

Comment: @Triatticus: $vv^T$ is supposed to be the dot product in the original question of the OP and the first line of this answer. Look at what the OP has asked for. Plus, I don't think if the dimension of it were larger the situation would've been any better. It will probably become worse.

Comment: No because it is dotted with $a$ so it must be of the form $v^T a$ and it doesn't matter where the other v is because the dotted term is a scalar, the only way to rearrange it to make sense is to break it down how this answer does

Comment: @Triatticus: as my counter-example shows, it does matter where the other $\vec{v}$ is because the expression lacks associativity. In general, $(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}) \vec{a} = (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{a}) \vec{v}$ is certainly wrong when $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent. It's very obvious. If you claim the otherwise, prove it. Even expanding them and writing them out in components show that they don't have to be equal. The LHS is a scalar of $\vec{a}$ and the RHS is a scalar of $\vec{v}$. Hence, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{v}$ have to be linearly dependent which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @stressed-out Please note that I'm ***not*** claiming $(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{a} = (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{v}$. The dot product is $v^T a$, ***not*** $v a^T$ as you insist. This being the case 
$$
(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{a})\vec{v} = (v^T a)v = v(v^T a) = (vv^T)a
$$

Comment: @caverac: Yes, if we work with column vectors then $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{v} = a^Tv$. It doesn't matter whether we work with column vectors or row vectors, I think. They are isomorphic. The problem is not fixed because your last step is still wrong. $\vec{v}(\vec{v}^T\vec{a}) \neq (\vec{v}\vec{v}^T)\vec{a}$. You can't move the parentheses just like that. It's not associative. So, if the dot product in physics has the same meaning as it has in mathematics, that identity is definitely and obviously wrong when $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @stressed-out Yes you can, it's called the "associative property"

Comment: @caverac: No, you can't. As I said, the "associative property" does not hold here. Not every algebraic structure has to be associative. See my counter-example. How do you justify that? Plus, the "associative property" works when you're dealing with a binary operation $*$ and you have $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$ in some algebraic structure. Here, you have two different operations, namely the dot product defined on $V \times V$ and a scalar product that's defined on $\mathbb{R} \times V$ where $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space.

Comment: @stressed-out 

$$
\{v v^T\}a = \left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)(1~0)\right\}\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$
\{v^T a\}v = \left\{(1~0) \left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right\}\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right) = 0\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)
$$

I am definitely failing at grasping what is your actual concern

Comment: @caverac: This is super cool. I checked it by writing the components and it works! It will go straight to my notes. Even though the first line is not a dot product anymore but the equality that we need for this answer to work holds and I retract my objection. I think you were talking about the tensor product and all the time I was like "what operation on vectors is he/she talking about?". :)